# Get filename without extension from full path

Tags: java, filenames

I am making a program to store data from excel files in database.  I would like the user to give in console the full path of the file and after the program to take only the file name to continue.

The code for loading the full path is:

```
String strfullPath = "";
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please enter the fullpath of the file");
strfullPath = scanner.nextLine();
String file = strfullPath.substring(strfullPath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
System.out.println(file.substring(0, file.indexOf('.')));
```

After that I would like to have: `String filename = .......`

The full path that the user would type would be like this: `C:\\Users\\myfiles\\Documents\\test9.xls`

The filename that I would create would take only the name without the `.xls`!
Could anyone help me how I would do this?

How i would do it if i would like to take as filename "test9.xls" ? –

Comment: change '/' to '\\' *String file = strfullPath.substring(strfullPath.lastIndexOf('\\') + 1);*

Comment: How i would do it if i would like to take as filename "test9.xls" ?

Answer (score 41):

You can do it like this:

```
String fname = file.getName();
int pos = fname.lastIndexOf(".");
if (pos > 0) {
    fname = fname.substring(0, pos);
}
```

or you can use the [apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/io/FilenameUtils.html#removeExtension%28java.lang.String%29):

```
String fileNameWithOutExt = FilenameUtils.removeExtension(fileNameWithExt);
```

Comment: +1 For not re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: thanks for FilenameUtils!

Comment: Plus one for using the small snippet which uses pure java code instead of third party libraries.

Answer (score 40):

I usually use this solution described in other post:

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils;

String basename = FilenameUtils.getBaseName(fileName);
```

Answer (score 23):

You could use the [`File`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) class to get the file name:

```
File userFile = new File(strfullPath);
String filename = userFile.getName();
```

Using a `File` object has numerous benefits, including the ability to test the file exists:

```
if (userFile.isFile()) {
  // Yay, it's a valid file (not a directory and not an invalid path)
}
```

You also need to check the file has an extension before you try and strip it:

```
if (filename.indexOf(".") > 0) {
    filename = filename.substring(0, filename.lastIndexOf("."));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call the `file.getName()` method that returns the name of the file as String. Then you cut the extension.

```
String fileName = file.getName();
fileName = fileName.substring(0, fileName.lastIndexOf(".")+1);
```

Comment: If the file has no extension, the `fileName` will become `""`.

Comment: @AndrewThompson taking that in consideration, this is the only approach that don't fail if the filename has "." besides the extension.

Comment: should be fileName.lastIndexOf(".") - 1 not fileName.lastIndexOf(".")+1

Answer (score 1):

```
if (!filename.equals(""))    
{
        String [] fileparts = filename.split("\\.");
        String filename = fileparts[0]; //Get first part
}
```

Comment: In the future when answering questions please provide an explanation with any code samples explaining why this will work.

Comment: This fails to consider that a filename might have many dots.  For example  vendor.prod.min.js  or some such.